# Where the opportunity competitor's picklist value stores?

Tags: opportunity

The default function of Salesforce's opportunity is with a competitors relation list.

And, admin can setup the competitor list for the whole Org.

I just wonder where the list stores in the Salesforce.

It's not in the OpportunityCompetitor object, and have found no answer in the official manual.

I want to delete the value at all.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list of competitors is essentially a picklist that has some slightly different properties than a standard picklist.  The field is called CompetitorName and resides on the OpportunityCompetitor object.  An admin can manage the list, but unlike a typical picklist, it will allow a user to save the record with a value that did not come from the picklist.

Comment: No, the object OpportunityCompetitor is used to store the competitors, but not the picklist value.

Comment: If there's only competitor picklist value, but no any competitor is added to any opportunity, then in the case, we will find nothing in the OpportunityCompetitor object.

Comment: CompetitorName is an attribute of the OpportunityCompetitor object, and that attribute is special picklist as I described above. When you create an OpportunityCompetitor record, you either pick a competitor from the list, or add a new one, free text.

Comment: How to write an Apex code to retrieve the attribute?

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums?id=906F00000008zdLIAQ Change line 07 from "Account" to "OpportunityCompetitor" and Line 16 from "Industry" to "CompetitorName"